# Disable submit button until input fields are completed

Tags: jquery, html

I want make the submit button disabled until all field are completed, I search in stackoverflow, but I can't apply codes. I try this, but then filled fields same disabled button.

```
  <form action="login" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input_class_big_e" placeholder="Email"/><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" class="input_class_big_p1" placeholder="Password"/><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" id="confirm_button_login" value="Login"/>
       </form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      if ($('#email, #password1').val().length == 0) {
        $("#confirm_button_login").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
      else {
        $("#confirm_button_login").removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcbkg3Lc/)

Comment: I d rather suggest you should use jQuery from validation plugin which has better functions and the possibilities to customize the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcbkg3Lc/1/) update. I just set 'disabled' property on submit button in html. In js script initialize change function on these two inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#email, #password1').change(function(){
        if($("#email").val().length && $("#password1").val().length){
                $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
                $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});

<input type="submit" id="confirm_button_login" value="Login" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the word "required" at the end of the  tag, will ensure that the user has filled out the field before continuing. See below.

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input_class_big_e" placeholder="Email" required><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" class="input_class_big_p1" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" id="confirm_button_login" value="Login" required>
       </form>
```